# union all with #temptable exist condition in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I got

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table tempdb..#temp
select * into #temp from (SELECT * FROM table2) then original SELECT for UNION
```

but I am getting syntax error?

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'then original SELECT for UNION'? You cannot have a `UNION ALL` with an `IF`...You cannot have a `SELECT INTO` as part of an `INSERT INTO`. Explain what you actually want otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Your query makes no sense. It looks like a hodge podge of various sql statements all smashed together. There are so many problems it is hard to know where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think it will help you to drop the table before the insert.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null 
    drop table tempdb..#temp

SELECT * INTO #temp
FROM table2

INSERT INTO TABLE3
SELECT *
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM #temp
```

Comment: Hi @Stephan, thanks for the reply. I did what you suggested but again I got some problem for select * into  #temp from (select SELECT * FROM table2). just updated original query. thanks

Comment: You can't have a select into in a insert. I edited my code again. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks @Stephan, I just also moved insert onto #temp before main insert into got the result. thanks